# save data to array and print array in rails

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails

In my code I am trying to print an array within email body. This is where I retrieve data.

```
    companies = ProjectCompany.find_by(project_id: project_id)
```

I try to print it as below within message body of my email.

```
company: <b>#{companies["company_name"]}</b>
```

But it just print first item of the array. How can I print all elements of the array.

Comment: Share you model code which for Project, ProjectCompany and Company(I guessed model names based on the question, share whatever you have)

Comment: of what array, `find_by` returns a single item, use `where` is you want multiple items.

Comment: And `where` returns an ActiveRecord::Relation - not an array.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller, get the companies like this:

```
@project_companies = ProjectCompany.where(project_id: project_id).includes(:company)
```

In your view, list them like this:

```
<b>Companies</b>
<ul>
  <% @project_companies.each do |project_company| %>
    <li><%= project_company.company.name %></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```